# ASP.NET: WebMethod: PageMethods.GetRate is not a function

Tags: asp.net, webmethod

When I try to access web method I obtain error:

```
PageMethods.GetRate is not a function;
```

My method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static string GetRate(string date)
    {
        return "qwe123";
    }
```

Register assembly:

```
    <%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="aspajax" %>
```

Script manager:

```
    <aspajax:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnGetRateComplete(result)
    {
        alert(result);
    }

    $(function() { $( "#<%=dtSignDate.ClientID %>" ).datepicker({ onSelect: function(date) { PageMethods.GetRate(date, OnGetRateComplete); }}); });
</script>
```

*GetRate* method is visible in generated page source.

**What is wrong?**

Comment: If GetRate method is visible in page source then you can quickly check if its a stand-alone function or part of "PageMethods" object?

Comment: var PageMethods = function() {
PageMethods.initializeBase(this);
this._timeout = 0;
this._userContext = null;
this._succeeded = null;
this._failed = null;
}
PageMethods.prototype = {
_get_path:function() {
 var p = this.get_path();
 if (p) return p;
 else return PageMethods._staticInstance.get_path();},
GetRate:function(date,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
...

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you applied the ScriptService attribute to your web service?  i.e.

```
[ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

Comment: This is page, not web service.

Answer (score 0):

well,u want to deal with ajax,then use $.ajax() is a good simple way to request the WebMethod.
[take a look at this question, u will get help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122449/bootstraptable-onloaderrors-param-status-post-url-is-asp-net-webmethod/49142988#49142988)

request url is [XX.aspx/GetRate], method:[POST]