# bootstrapTable onLoadError's param [status], post url is ASP.NET WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, post, webmethod, http-status-codes, bootstrap-table

now,I'm try to use bootstrapTable to load my data that using ASP.NET WebMethod.

$.ajax(): url is set like this: "url:mydata.aspx/GetData"
and this is work fine.

in the other way:

```
$('#mytab').bootstrapTable({
    method: 'post',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    url:"mydata.aspx/GetData",
    toolbar: '#toolbar',
    striped: true, 
    dataField: "res",
    pageNumber: 1,
    pagination:true,
    queryParamsType:'limit',
    queryParams:queryParams,
    sidePagination:'server',
    pageSize:10,
    pageList:[5,10,20,30],
    showRefresh:true,
    showColumns:true,
    clickToSelect: true,
    toolbarAlign:'right',
    buttonsAlign:'right',
    toolbar:'#toolbar',
    columns:[
        {
            title:'全选',
            field:'select',
            checkbox:true,
            width:25,
            align:'center',
            valign:'middle'
        },
        {
            title:'ID',
            field:'ID',
            visible:false
        },
        {
            title:'登录名',
            field:'LoginName',
            sortable:true
        },
        {
            title:'姓名',
            field:'Name',
            sortable:true
        },
        {
            title:'手机号',
            field:'Tel',
        },
        {
            title:'邮箱',
            field:'Email'
        },
        {
            title:'注册日期',
            field:'CreateTime',
            sortable:true
        },
        {
            title:'状态',
            field:'Attribute',
            align:'center',
            formatter:operateFormatter
        }
    ],
    responseHandler:function(res){
        return res;
    },
    onLoadError: function(status){
        alert("error"+status);
    }
})

function operateFormatter(value,row,index){
    。。。
}

function queryParams(params){
    return{
        pageSize: params.limit,
        pageIndex:params.pageNumber,
        content:$('#search_name').val()
    }
}
```

ASP.NET API code here

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData(int pageSize, int pageIndex, string content)
{
  return "{total:200,rows:[{......}]}";
}
```

But now I got an error code:

```
[error200]has been alerted.
```

I want to know [onLoadError]'s error status's map
   200:XXXX
   400:XXXX
   500:XXXX

bootstrapTable document has no error status map information.
please help........

Comment: is this status http's status code?  well, if so, 200 lead to error? why this result?

Answer (score 0):

Paste your JSON data into myjson.com and really make sure it's good json (without errors).  Then post a JSFiddle with a subset of your code and using the url from   the myjson.com link it provides.